# About gridview events

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using following code:

```
protected void gvDetails_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    e.Row.Attributes["ondblclick"] = "location.href='CustomerInfo.aspx?page=0&Custid=" + Convert.ToString(e.Row.FindControl("hdfCust_Id")) + "'";

 }
```

so when I double click on the gridview it redirects me to next page and give error.
The value of Custid it gives as follows:

```
Custid=System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField
```

Comment: You should at least have tried something at your own end, before asking the question. This is a simple logical issue that is left there because you forgot something

Answer (score 3):

you need

```
 ((HiddenFiled)e.Row.FindControl("hdfCust_Id")).Value
```

Combining the above

```
e.Row.Attributes["ondblclick"] = "location.href='CustomerInfo.aspx?page=0&Custid=" 
      + ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hdfCust_Id")).Value + "'";
```

### Edit 1

As `Convert.ToString(e.Row.FindControl("hdfCust_Id"))` output will be `System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField`

And `((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hdfCust_Id")).Value` will be your required value